# Limit of random variables sequence

Tags: probability

I need a clever way to find the limit of $$\frac{\sin(\pi X_1)+\sin(\pi X_2) + \dots + \sin(\pi X_n)}{n},$$ where $X_i$ are independent random variables with the distribution $\mathbb{P}(X_n=\frac{-n}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=\frac{n}{2})=\frac{1}{2}$.

It obviously calls for the (strong) law of large numbers, but how exactly make $X_n$'s iid? I tried defining $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{n}\Rightarrow X_i=nY_i$ and then looking for $$\frac{\sin(\pi Y_1)+\sin(2\pi Y_2) + \dots + \sin(n\pi Y_n)}{n}$$ but if this limit equals to $\mathbb{E}\sin(\pi Y_1)=0$, then I need two sequences convergent to $0$ as upper and lower bound. Or is there some other way?

Comment: $\sin\pi X_j=0,\pm 1$ are the only possible values, so you can split this into a small number of separate sums each of which will have iid summands.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin(\pi X_{2k})=0$ and $\sin(\pi X_{2k+1})$ equals $-1$ or $+1$ with equal probability,
$$ \frac{Z_n}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$$
has mean zero and variance $\frac{1}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$.

Comment: And it converges almost surely to zero, by the strong law of large numbers.